# Should I ask my line manager whether I should apply for another job?

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, career-development, manager

I'm currently working on an hourly contract with this company, I love the job and I love the environment and my team, however, my contract is only 6 months (I'm covering for someone taking a sabbatical leave). I'm currently 3 months in.

My manager told me that she's really impressed with my performance and wants to keep me stable part of the team and that she told our CEO that recruiting me and someone else in the team was the best recruiting decision she's made but she needs to find a position for me. I've been helping with different projects aside from my main job, but I haven't heard anything back from her.

There's a new job opportunity in the same company that matches my qualifications, and I want to apply to it.

Should I ask my manager first and ask if there's any new info about me getting a stable position in my current team because I'm applying to somewhere different if there are no chances? and how should I go about this?

Answer (score 3):

If you want that position, apply for it.

If your manager asks why, politely explain that the current situation is that your contract ends in a couple months. As far as you know, you don't have a job after X day.

You should also be applying elsewhere.

Although i will say... 3 months out from the end is a little early. I'd wait until the 60 day mark before applying *internally*, and instead would at this point be pushing out applications other places... because why not. you never know what opportunities you're missing simply by not searching every once in a while.

Then when it gets closer to your end date, maybe if you haven't heard anything, put in an app for that company job.

It's also possible that if your contract doesn't have a specified end date, rather was just "about 6 months", depending on how it's worded and how th ecompany works, you may just stay on for a bit. If the other person comes back and you're not needed anymore that's an issue... but generally companies don't want to lose good employees. It's likely they are just busy and haven't thought proactively about your contract

Comment: What happens if the OP wants to continue their current job more (I found it hard to tell from the question) ?

Comment: @mattfreake - Unless the manager comes back to the author with a job offer, the author should assume, that their last day is per the contract.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds from your question like you would rather stay with your current manager, over the other job. If that is the case explain to your manager that you're really enjoying working with her and the team, but as the contract comes towards an end, you're going to start considering other roles and this one you've seen advertised has caught your eye. Explain that you need some kind of certainty, even if it's not as good as staying in the team would be.

At best this will focus her mind on sorting our a contract, at worse she'll explain that realistically she is unlikely to be able to sort anything.

And once you're reaching the end of the contract, keep applying and considering other roles until/unless you have a new contract. Words and promises are worth little :-)

Answer (score -1):

> Should I ask my manager first and ask if there's any new info about me getting a stable position in my current team because I'm applying to somewhere different if there are no chances? and how should I go about this?

You're essentially telling your employer that you are currently looking for a job and if they don't give you a position, you're going to quit.

That's not a good thing.

I would just ask your manager if you have a position with the team. Tell them that you are very interested and need to know very soon since your 6 months is about up. They will understand what you mean since there is a time constraint.

It is never a good idea to tell your employer that you're looking into other positions. It is a bad idea because despite the fact they like you, they can do without you (obviously since your contract is 6 months anyways). So it is best to tell them that you are interested in staying there and they will do what they can to get you a position.

Aside from that quietly look for another position and inform that OTHER position that you need a start date some time after your 6 months contract. That way if you have no position, you can tell them goodbye and go to your new job stress free. You can also tell your manager that you're interested in working there and that you wish to stay in contact in case a position does open.

In some cases the position may not open immediately due to budget constraints or whatnot. So it is best to be on good terms with your current employer and leave them in a good way. Tell them you're interested in staying, they'll look into it, work your 6 months, look for other jobs, have a job lined up to start after the 6 months, and if you have to leave you can tell them you're still interested in working there and leave your contact information and go to your new job.

Comment: I would assume OP plans to tell prospective employers that their start date would be X, where X is shortly after their current contract.  Looking for a job due to the end of your contract is typically not going to reflect badly on the employee.  That said, typically employers don't want to have a start date 90 days out; OP is starting on this process a bit early.